# vite build not working in development as well as on vercel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vite, vercel

I'm trying to run vite build to test , before deploying on vercel. I get

```
'vite' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

if i run  node vite build, i get

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\tunji\Desktop\airbnb-clone\client\vite'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

but if i run

```
cd client && npm install && node .\\node_modules\\vite\\bin\\vite.js build
```

it works, but when I'm trying to deploy to vercel, it doesn't work